# Python Popen adding current directory to arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

Trying to use subprocess.Popen() to run a command with a file path as an argument. This fails and it seems Popen() is adding the current directory to the argument list passed to the command.

```
phil@mas-xubuntu:~/Downloads/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/bin$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> vm_root = "/mas_data/vms/"
>>> vm_path = "\"" + vm_root + "XP VM 1/XP VM 1.vmx\""
>>> vm_path
'"/mas_data/vms/XP VM 1/XP VM 1.vmx"'
>>> subprocess.Popen(["vmrun", "start", vm_path])
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f6b9225c898>
>>> Error: Cannot open VM: /home/phil/Downloads/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/bin/"/mas_data/vms/XP VM 1/XP VM 1.vmx", unknown file suffix
exit()
phil@mas-xubuntu:~/Downloads/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/bin$ vmrun start "/mas_data/vms/XP VM 1/XP VM 1.vmx"
<VM launches>
```

Not sure what I'm missing to get Popen to work and execute the command `vmrun start "/mas_data/vms/XP VM 1/XP VM 1.vmx"`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't surround the path in quotes. There's no need for that when using `Popen`, the quotes only cause the path to be invalid.

Comment: you need that in `Popen` when passing only single string argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're working too hard for this. This `Popen` syntax:

```
subprocess.Popen(["vmrun", "start", vm_path])
```

already quotes arguments against blanks (as opposed to the one where you painstakingly compose your own command line as a single string, I don't recommend that)

Since you also add quotes, it passes the quotes litterally and it fails. Just do:

```
vm_path = vm_root + "XP VM 1/XP VM 1.vmx"
```

or maybe better:

```
vm_path = os.path.join(vm_root,"XP VM 1/XP VM 1.vmx")
```

and you'll be fine.

Answer (score -1):

Path with spaces needs to be handled. 
The program is failing because of the space:

"/mas_data/vms/XP VM 1/XP VM 1.vmx"

Please modify the directory name and file name to remove the space and check
"/mas_data/vms/XP_VM_1/XP_VM_1.vmx"